# Passing an argument to cmd.exe

Tags: c#, .net

I am attempting to ping a local computer from my C# program. To accomplish this, I'm using the following code.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
proc.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
proc.Arguments = @"""ping 10.2.2.125""";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
```

This opens a command-line window, but ping is not invoked. What is the reason?

Comment: call the ping command directly

Comment: @Matt How would I go about doing that in c#?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to include the "/c" argument to tell cmd.exe what you mean it to do:

```
proc.Arguments = "/c ping 10.2.2.125";
```

(You *could* call ping.exe directly of course. There are times when that's appropriate, and times when it's easier to call `cmd`.)

Comment: @whihathac: "it doesn't work" doesn't give much information. What happens for you?

Comment: hi how can I store the process output in string to display the output in my own application without opening the console window

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee: That sounds like an entirely different question to me - so I suggest you ask it in a new post (after searching for answers here, of course).

Answer (score 11):

```
public void ExecuteCommand(String command)
{
   Process p = new Process();
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
   startInfo.Arguments = @"/c " + command; // cmd.exe spesific implementation
   p.StartInfo = startInfo;
   p.Start();
}
```

**Usage:** `ExecuteCommand(@"ping google.com -t");`

Comment: /K     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
          This is useful for testing, to examine variables

Comment: /K is default for me. :)

Answer (score 9):

```
cmd /C
```

or

```
cmd /K
```

Probably /C because /K does not terminate right away

Answer (score 6):

You could just use the [`System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx).

```
    public static int GetPing(string ip, int timeout)
    {
        int p = -1;
        using (Ping ping = new Ping())
        {
                PingReply reply = ping.Send(_ip, timeout);
                if (reply != null)
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        p = Convert.ToInt32(reply.RoundtripTime);
        }
        return p;
    }
```

Comment: Good alternative but for all you know he wants to display the output to the user or on a console window.

Comment: This answer was based on the comments on the question wherein Matt suggested calling Ping directly, and the OP asked how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 2):

To call the ping command directly, do as you have in your question, but substitute `cmd.exe` with `ping.exe`:

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\ping.exe";
proc.Arguments = @"10.2.2.125";
Process.Start(proc);
```