# How to close command prompt?

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

            psi.UseShellExecute = true;
            psi.Verb = "runas";
            psi.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";

            psi.Arguments = "/env /user:" + "Administrator" + @" %windir%\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f";

            Process.Start(psi);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\DllRegister.bat");
            /// need to close the command prompt over here ????????????????

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding "exit" as an argument. "exit" is the sytax to close CMD as i remember

Comment: Why do you execute cmd.exe to run another program if you can run that program directly?

Comment: yes but it is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing an argument to cmd.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047171/passing-an-argument-to-cmd-exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `/C` modifier instead of `/K`

```
psi.Arguments = "/env /user:" + "Administrator" + @" %windir%\System32\cmd.exe /C %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f";
```

The diffrence between these two is as follows

```
/C  Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K  Carries out the command specified by string but remains
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the command line [argument](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true) `/c` instead of `/k` to your arguments to execute the command and then terminate the command shell.