# Running tests from other assembly with MSTest

Tags: c#, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I have an issue here, as soon as I hit compile , mstest cmd prompt shows up then it crashes/goes away and my test won't get executed.
This is the code :

```
 public void test(String testContainer, String testName)
    {

       // String Path = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 Common7\IDE\mstest.exe";
          String Path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe";
       // String Path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""";



         Process myProcess = new Process();
       // ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path, "/testsettings:local.testsettings /testcontainer:" + testContainer + " /test:" + testName);
       ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path, "MSTest/testcontainer:" + testContainer + " /test:" + testName + @"/testcategory:""ActionCol""");

       myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
       myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;

       myProcess.Start();
      // MessageBox.Show(x + "\n" + y);
    }
```

And this is how I call this method :

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            x = @"C:\Users\butoiu.edward\Desktop\Lucru\SimarpiUnitTest\GestcollTestSolution\CodedUITestProject\bin\Debug\GestcollTestProject.dll";
            y = "ActionCollInsert";
            test(x, y);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong ? Really need some help here, thanks in advance

EDIT 1 - this is how a testmethod looks like in my other project., forgot to mention I have 2 projects under the same solution ( doesn't change a thing, but I think it's worth mentioning)

```
[TestMethod(), TestCategory("ActionCol")]
        public void ActionCollInsert()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test");

            //using the proper map
            var actionColTest = new ActionColMap();
            //actionColTest.ActionColOpen1();

            // actionColTest.ActionColSlider();
            actionColTest.ActionColHideCollumns();

            actionColTest.ActionColInsert();

            actionColTest.ActionColInsertCode();
            actionColTest.ActionColInsertDesc();
            actionColTest.ActionColSave();

        }
```

EDIT2 - How I start DEV-CMD - using shell to start my cmd from it's shortcut's position fixed up things for me.As I fixed this issue, a new one appeared. I can't pass arguments into the cmd, I mean nothing happens.

```
public void test(String testContainer, String testName)
        {

           //   String Path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe";
            String Path = @"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2012\Visual Studio Tools\Developer Command Prompt for VS2012.lnk"; 

             Process myProcess = new Process();
           // ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path, "/testsettings:local.testsettings /testcontainer:" + testContainer + " /test:" + testName);
           ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path, "MSTest/testcontainer:" + testContainer + " /test:" + testName );

            myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "blah blah"; // - this ain't working !!!!
            myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;

           myProcess.Start();

        }
```

EDIT3 - I am able to start a cmd and pass some arguments to it ( source : [Passing an argument to cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047171/passing-an-argument-to-cmd-exe)). But changing the path to my dev cmd prompt will not insert automatically the parameter. Need some help, /c has no effect on dev cmd.

```
            ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
            proc.FileName = Path;
            proc.Arguments = @"/c ping 10.2.2.125";
            proc.UseShellExecute = true;
            Process.Start(proc);
```

Comment: are you shure it crashes? are there any exceptions? can you show the part where the actual test is declared (with Category etc..). Maybe its a problem that there are no whitespaces between the cmd-line-args?

Comment: There are no exceptions, I've tried try-catching the whole method to see if it throws something. No errors whatsoever, also running mstest.exe from the directory directly by me will have  the same behaviour. The app starts, I can see the window, then it disappears in less than a second, behaving like a bat, please check my post, I've edited it ( I think I wrote crash earlier, sorry )

Comment: I made a form with a button that executes this action, pressing that button x times will cause the appear-disappear of mstest.exe x times, my project isn't crashing or throwing any kind of error.

Comment: Can you execute the command by hand using cmd?

Comment: I can manually execute it by doing this:
- starting Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 ( if I manually execute MSTest.exe it will have the same behavior when I execute it through my app)
- writing MSTest/testcontainer: fullURL /testcategory: whatever.So yeah it works manually by using dev cmd but not mstest.

I've tried running Dev cmd for VS2012 from my C# app but I get an error ( file not found ), check out my code, that's how the actual url of it looks like (the .bat exec)

Comment: From what it looks like, I need to execute DEV CMD for VS2012, but I fail to do so due it's weird targeting

Comment: as dumb as it may sound, i guess you have to call it over explicit call to cmd.exe like ´Process.Start("cmd.exe /C \"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat\"")´ and so on. Unfortunately, this is my only idea :(

Comment: third edit, I only need to find out how to pass arguments to this dev cmd and I'm done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59267/discussion-between-nozzleman-and-extremeswat).

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating Batch script which can build environment for mstest and trigger the test accordingly

please find below example. you just need to replace correct path for **vcvarsall.bat** for your system

```
cd\
cd "Program Files <x86>"\"Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0"\VC
call "vcvarsall.bat"
cd\
C:
Mstest /testcontainer:Test.dll /resultsfile:result.trx
```

Comment: I will give it a try and return with an answer, thanks !